# Adjacent CSS Selector with plain text in between still matching

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have text like:

```
Line 1
<br>
<br>
<br>
Line 2
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Line 3
```

I don't have control over the HTML nor can I use JavaScript (i.e. I can literally only use CSS), but I need to hide subsequent consecutive line breaks.

The issue is this selector:

```
(parent selector) br+br {display:none}
```

Hides all of the line breaks in between Line 2 and Line 3 - the adjacent selector doesn't appear to care about any text not contained in an element.

Am I out of luck with this one, or is there some way to break the adjacent selector when there is plain text between the elements?

Comment: Is the number of `<br />` elements always known in advance / constant?

Comment: @Ihazkode No, the content is taken from emails so it will vary.

Comment: I could be wrong here but... In that case I think you are indeed out of luck because CSS operates based on nodes and ignores raw text in-between.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the number of br tags is consistent, you could hide all line breaks, and only show certain ones instead of trying to hide specific ones. The point being that it's easier to select a few things than it is to select a lot of things

```
br {
  display: none;
}
br:nth-child(4n) {
  display: initial;
}
```

This requires that the number of breaks is consistent between lines though. There is no way to select plain text in CSS, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've decided this is an acceptably mediocre solution:

Since line breaks generally come in pairs displaying the 3rd consecutive helps limit the whitespace in a way that works better than just undoing the br+br rule.

```
(parent selector) br+br+br {
     display:initial
}
```